# How to finish activity A from activity C

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 3 activities A->B->C.
I want to finish activity A on activity C created. but if on activity B pressed back button activity A comes front.

Comment: Perhaps you should not have three activities. If A and B are that tightly coupled, such that B starting C somehow affects A, make A and B be one activity, not two.

Comment: you can set activity A to noHistory=true in the manifest, but then your application will close when back is pressed on Activity B

Comment: Use this :
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);
finish();  To finish Current acitivty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can acheive it in the following way :

Step 1: When calling Activity B

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A, B.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Step 2 : From B to c :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(B, C.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: on Activity C when i pressed back button Activity A came front

Comment: Have you checked it right? The flags that I have added when creating C is that which clears the backstack of activites and hence A also gets destroyed.

Comment: i found another way

`//in activity A:
public static AppCompatActivity var_name;

onCreate(){
if(var_name == null)
{
 var_name = this;
}
}

//on activity C:
onCreate(){

 A.var_name.finish();
}`

Comment: Never do that.. U are using strong reference and tight coupling over there because of which u run into memory issues.

Comment: Uuh.. what a dangerous way :-)... by the way is there another way?